# libusb failing at getting string descriptor on some devices

Tags: c++, libusb

I am trying to get information about all attached devices.

This is my code:

```
libusb_device_descriptor desc;
libusb_config_descriptor *conDesc;
char szBuffer[256] = { 0 };
unsigned char strDesc[256];
libusb_device_handle *devHandle = NULL;
int retVal = 0;
__int64 i64Temp;
DWORD dwProdId;
DWORD dwProdId1;
i64Temp = 13888;
dwProdId = (DWORD)i64Temp;

retVal = libusb_open(dev, &devHandle);


int r = libusb_get_device_descriptor(dev, &desc);
if (r < 0)
{
    cout << "failed to get device descriptor" << endl;
    return;
}
r = libusb_get_config_descriptor(dev, 0, &conDesc);
printf("Interface Class = %d\n", conDesc->interface->altsetting->bInterfaceClass);
cout << "Number of possible configurations: " << (int)desc.bNumConfigurations << "" << endl;
cout << "Device Class: " << desc.bDeviceClass << endl;
cout << "Device Class: " << desc.bDeviceSubClass << endl;
printf("Class = %d\n", desc.bDeviceClass);
cout << "VendorID: " << desc.idVendor << endl;
cout << "ProductID: " << desc.idProduct << endl;
if (retVal == LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
{
    retVal = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(devHandle, desc.iManufacturer, strDesc, 256);
    printf("Manufacturer: %s\n", strDesc);
    retVal = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(devHandle, desc.iSerialNumber, strDesc, 256);
    printf("SerialNumber: %s\n", strDesc);
    retVal = libusb_get_string_descriptor_ascii(devHandle, desc.iProduct, strDesc, 256);
    printf("Product: %s\n", strDesc);
    printf("\n\n");
}
else if (retVal != LIBUSB_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("retVal failed");
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

My code knows that there are 8 devices connected but it's getting manufacturer or serial number only on two of them. I would like to get this information for all of the attached devices.

Comment: That information might not be available/set on all devices. 

As a sanity check you could write a quick script, in either python or javascript for example, that would do the same thing as your c++ program. This will isolate any issues with libusb and/or your program.

Comment: I cant write script right now, however i tried to two pendrives (ADATA, Sandisk) i can see the names in other programs like Zadig so i should be able to see it with libusb right?

Comment: Ow my bad its failing on retVal = libusb_open(dev, &devHandle); retVal is -12 on other devices http://i.imgur.com/gEvvfKL.png?1